# How to prepare a RGB array and the rowpointer for png_write_image?

Tags: c, libpng

I am quite new to C and need a bit help with the libpng.
I have an unsigned char array filled with the RGB values of an image and need to create a .png image. I managed to create an image with the right size and kinda filled in the pixel values but the Original Picture looks like this:
[image: Original picture]
and my code does this:
[image: new picture]

Am I right that the pixel values have to be stored in an unsigned char array as: pixel one red, pixel one green, pixel one blue, pixel two red, pixel two green, pixel two blue,...
And do I calculate the row pointers in the code below correctly?

Building the pixel array (form Y,Cb,Cr values to RGB):

```
int wcnt = 0;

for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){
  for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){

    rgb[wcnt] = round(1.0 * _y[y][x] + 0.0 * _cb[y][x] + 1.402 * _cr[y][x]);        //red
    rgb[wcnt+1] = round(1.0 * _y[y][x] + (-0.34414 * _cb[y][x]) + (-0.71414 * _cr[y][x]));  //green
    rgb[wcnt+2] = round(1.0 * _y[y][x] + 1.772 * _cb[y][x] + 0.0 * _cr[y][x]);  //blue

    wcnt = wcnt +3;
  }
}
```

Writing the PNG:

```
int writepng(char* name, char* dest){   
    char decpng[256];
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    png_structp png_ptr = NULL;
    png_infop info_ptr = NULL;
    png_bytep row_pointers[height];

    sprintf(decpng, "%s%s_dec.png", dest, name);

    //Create File
    fp = fopen(decpng, "wb");
    if (fp == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "PNG konnte nicht angelegt werden!\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Information init
    png_ptr = png_create_write_struct (PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (png_ptr == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "Schreibstruktur konnte nicht angelegt werden.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    info_ptr = png_create_info_struct(png_ptr);
    if (info_ptr == NULL){
      fprintf(stderr, "Infostruktur konnte nicht angelegt werden.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))){
      fprintf(stderr, "Fehler Initialisierung.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    png_init_io(png_ptr, fp);

    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))){
      fprintf(stderr, "Fehler beim schreiben des Headers.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    png_set_IHDR(png_ptr, info_ptr, width, height, 8, PNG_COLOR_TYPE_RGB, PNG_INTERLACE_NONE, PNG_COMPRESSION_TYPE_DEFAULT, PNG_FILTER_TYPE_DEFAULT);

    png_write_info(png_ptr, info_ptr);

    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(png_ptr))){
      fprintf(stderr, "Fehler beim schreiben der Daten.\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //Fill PNG - here is something wrong

    for(int k = 0; k < height; k++){
      //k = each line, k*width = pixels till first pixel of like k, *3 = RGB values
      row_pointers[k] = (rgb + k * width * 3);
    }

    //png_struct, png_bytep
    png_write_image(png_ptr, row_pointers);

    png_write_end(png_ptr, info_ptr);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: I checked `writepng` function by using dummy data and it worked correctly. There maybe something wrong with how you prepare `rgb` array...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The writepng function works fine, i just f*cked up the arrays _y,_cb,_cr. I might have been braindead while defining the arrays with malloc.

Comment: @DRG could you summarize your solution briefly and post it as an answer to your question?  Thank you